# How to save markers latitude and longitude into MySQL database table using python

Tags: python, mysql, html, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

I have a google map with a HTML form. The user searches for his location and places a marker. After clicking on the marker the form pops up and after filling the form and clicking submit the data gets stored into the MySQL database table.

However I also want the location of the user, that is where the user has placed the marker, its latitude and longitude to be stored into the MySQL database table.

I am using Python 2.7 for the processing part, i.e. for inserting data into the MySQL database from the form.

I am using Mac OS Sierra.

I am using Python,MySQL and Apache that is already pre-installed on mac.

Since I am new to coding, can please someone tell me what I need to add to my code for it to run smoothly.

I am attaching my HTML as well as Python code below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>MAPS</title>

  <style>
   #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   }

   html, body {
       height: 100%;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }

   #description {
       font-family: Calibri;
       font-size: 15px;
       font-weight: 300;
   }

   #infowindow-content .title {
       display: none;
   }

   
   #map #infowindow-content {
       display: none;
   }

   .pac-card {
       margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
       border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
       box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       outline: none;
       box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
       background-color: #fff;
       font-family: Calibri;
   }

   #pac-container {
       padding-bottom: 12px;
       margin-right: 12px;
   }

   .pac-controls {
       display: inline-block;
       padding: 5px 11px;
   }

   .pac-controls label {
       font-family: Calibri;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: 400;
   }

      #pac-input {
          background-color: #fff;
          font-family: Calibri;
          font-size: 15px;
          font-weight: 400;
          margin-left: 12px;
          padding: 8px 12px;
          text-overflow: ellipsis;
          width: 400px;
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
          border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
          color: #fff;
          background-color: #4d90fe;
          font-size: 25px;
          font-weight: 400;
          padding: 6px 12px;
      }

      #target {
       width: 345px;
      }

      #form
   {
    display: none;
   }

      #heading {
       text-align: center;
       color: #003366;
       font-size: 30px;
       font-family: Calibri;
       padding: 8px 12px;
   }

      label.field {
       text-align: left;
       font-weight: bolder;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-family: Calibri;
   }

   input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=number], select {
       font-family: Calibri;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: bolder;
       padding: 8px 12px;
       width: 100%;
       margin: 8px 0;
       display: inline-block;
       border: 1px solid black;
       border-radius: 4px;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   input[type=submit] {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bolder;
       background-color: white;
       color: #00b300;
       padding: 8px 12px;
       margin: 8px 0;
       border: 2px solid #00b300;
       border-radius: 4px;
       cursor: pointer;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   input[type=submit]:hover {
       background-color: #00b300;
       color: white;
      }

      input[type=reset] {
       font-family: Calibri;
       font-size: 16px;
       font-weight: bolder;
       background-color: white;
       color: #cc0000;
       padding: 8px 12px;
       margin: 8px 0;
       border: 2px solid #cc0000;
       border-radius: 4px;
       cursor: pointer;
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }

   input[type=reset]:hover {
       background-color: #cc0000;
       color: white;
      }

      input[type=text]:focus {
       background-color: #f2f2f2;
       border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      input[type=email]:focus {
       background-color: #f2f2f2;
       border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      input[type=number]:focus {
       background-color: #f2f2f2;
       border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      select:focus {
       background-color: #f2f2f2;
       border-color: #4d90fe;
      }
  </style>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyC8EAfEQrYVs4c_kMBUQw3tVY8uhEViDCU&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
                async defer>
        </script>  
   
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search your location..." />
  <div id="form">
   <form action="/cgi-bin/processing.py" method="post">
      <p id="heading">PERSONAL INFORMATION</p>
     <label class="field" for="fullname"><b>Full Name:</b></label>
     <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Eg. Suraj Makhija" size="30" required />
     <br />
     <br />
     <label class="field" for="emailid"><b>E-mail:</b></label>
     <input type="email" name="emailid" placeholder="Eg. contact@domain.com" size="30" required />
     <br />
     <br />
     <label class="field" for="mobile"><b>Mobile:</b></label>
     <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Eg. 9999999999" maxlength="10" minlength="10" size="30" required />
     <br />
     <br />
     <label class="field" for="gender"><b>Gender:</b></label>
     <select name="gender" required>
       <option value="male">Male</option>
       <option value="female">Female</option>
       <option value="other">Other</option>
     </select>
     <br />
     <br />
     <label class="field" for="areaofexpertise"><b>Area of Expertise:</b></label>
     <input type="text" name="areaofexpertise" placeholder="Eg. Android/iOS Developer" size="30" required />
     <br />
     <br />
     <label class="field" for="yearsofexperience"><b>Years of Experience:</b></label>
     <input type="number" name="yearsofexperience" placeholder="Eg. 10" min="0" max="100" required />
     <br />
     <br />
     <p style="text-align: center;">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
     <input type="reset" value="Clear All" /> 
     </p>
         </form>
        </div>

  <script>
   var map;
   var iconBase;
   var input;
   var searchBox;  
   var markers=[];   
        var markerArray =[];
        var infowindow;
        
      function initAutocomplete() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
             center: {lat: 20.5937, lng: 78.9629},
             zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            gestureHandling: 'cooperative'
          });

         //Declaring infowindow.
         infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: document.getElementById('form')
         });

            // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
         input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
         searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
         map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

            // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
         map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
            searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
         });

         //Creates a marker when the user clicks on a location on the map.
         google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          addMarker(event.latLng, map);
      });

            // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
            // more details for that place.
         searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
            var places = searchBox.getPlaces();
            if (places.length == 0) {
              return;
           }

            // Clear out the old markers.
           markers.forEach(function(marker) {
             marker.setMap(null);
           });
             
            // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
           var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
           places.forEach(function(place) {
             if (!place.geometry) {
                console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                return;
             }
            var icon = {
               url: place.icon,
               size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
               origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
               anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
               scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };
   // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
      }));
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
  }

   //Marker function declaration.
   function addMarker(location, map) {
      // Add the marker at the clicked location.
       var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/';
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          draggable: true,
       animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          position: location,
          map: map,
          icon: iconBase + 'ylw-blank.png'
      });
      //Infowindow pops up on clicking the marker.
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
       document.getElementById('form').style.display='inline-block';
             infowindow.open(map, marker);
           });
           var lat = marker.getPosition().lat();
   var lng = marker.getPosition().lng();
  }
  </script>

 </body>
```

Python code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python

import cgi

import MySQLdb

import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

fullname = form.getvalue('fullname', '')

emailid = form.getvalue('emailid', '')

mobile = form.getvalue('mobile', '')

gender = form.getvalue('gender', '')

areaofexpertise = form.getvalue('areaofexpertise', '')

yearsofexperience = form.getvalue('yearsofexperience', '')

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="suraj", db="client_database")

cursor = db.cursor()

query = """INSERT INTO client_info (FULL_NAME, EMAIL_ID, MOBILE, GENDER, AREA_OF_EXPERTISE, YEARS_OF_EXPERIENCE) 
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"""

cursor.execute(query, (fullname, emailid, mobile, gender, areaofexpertise, yearsofexperience))

result = cursor.fetchall()

db.commit()

db.close()
```

Comment: Why are you doing this using such low level APIs? why don't you use a high level platform like django which has makes this sort of thing sooooo much easier

Comment: What's wrong with your current code?

Comment: I am not understanding how to save the location of the user into MySQL database @Shadow

Comment: I am quite new to coding...once I get good with this I will move to django @e4c5

Comment: Sorry that's the wrong approach. You will be spending more than twice the effort in doing so. What you are writing now will have to be thrown away and you will spend for more time on it than you ever will spend learning django

Comment: Could you tell me what I need to add in my HTML and python code so that the markers location gets stored into the database @Shadow  Would be really helpful

Comment: Since you still have not answered what's wrong with your code, no I cannot help.

Comment: As of now, there nothing wrong in the code, its working fine and the user data is getting stored in the database. However I don't know how to store the users location. When I just add 2 more columns into my database for latitude and longitude it gives Internal Server Error...but that could be because i have not written anything in the python code for the data to get inserted...I am just assuming this part. @Shadow

Comment: Adding some error handling to the code would help with the error message. However, I do not see where you send the coordinates from the client to the server.

Comment: I just wish to save the coordinates into my database table, using apache on localhost. @Shadow